Ошибка: "Blocked aria-hidden on a <button> element"
Есть следующий код кнопки на TS, при нажатии на которую открывается выпадающий список:
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="menu">
    Кнопка
    <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</button>

Но при нажатии на элемент внутри выпадающего списка, появляется такая вот ошибка:
Blocked aria-hidden on a <button> element because the element that
just received focus must not be hidden from assistive technology
users. Avoid using aria-hidden on a focused element or its ancestor.
Consider using the inert attribute instead, which will also prevent
focus. For more details, see the aria-hidden section of the WAI-ARIA
specification at


P. S. В Интернете нашёл решение с заменой button на div, но не хотелось бы менять сам элемент, может можно как-нибудь по-другому?

Дубликат? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79159883/warning-blocked-aria-hidden-on-an-element-because-its-descendant-retained-focu
